# Handling null in sub queries

Tags: mysql, sql, join, null

I have two tables with me. Say one has list of actions (the original table that I work on has a list of messages sent and received) and the other is a user table, with the full name of the users. I have replicated an issue of what I have right now.

The users found in the actions table (messages table) may not be present in the users table. I am using a subquery to select the full name of the users against the username in the original query for the actions table. When the user in the actions table is not present in the users table, MySQL returns a *NULL* and this is expected. But instead, I want it to return the original username.

Say, `praveen` is there both in the users table as well as actions table. So, I get something like this: `Praveen Kumar likes something.`. Say, I have another username, `bluff` that is not present in the users table, and the action becomes this way: `NULL shares something.`. Here instead of *NULL*, is it possible to return the username itself, like `bluff shares something.`?

My [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2bdd/1), schema details and other references have been provided here. Let me know if I can do it in a better way. Thanks.

**MySQL 5.5.30 Schema Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE `users`
    (`username` varchar(15), `fullname` varchar(15))
;

INSERT INTO `users`
    (`username`, `fullname`)
VALUES
    ('praveen', 'Praveen Kumar'),
    ('jeff', 'Jeff Atwood')
;

CREATE TABLE `actions`
    (`user` varchar(7), `action` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO `actions`
    (`user`, `action`)
VALUES
    ('praveen', 'Like'),
    ('jeff', 'Comment'),
    ('praveen', 'Answer'),
    ('praveen', 'Share'),
    ('jeff', 'Comment'),
    ('bluff', 'Share'),
    ('jeff', 'Like')
;
```

**Query**

```
SELECT *, (
  SELECT `fullname` FROM `users` WHERE `user` = `username`
) AS `name` FROM `actions`
```

**[Result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2bdd/1/0)**

```
+---------+---------+---------------+
| USER    | ACTION  | NAME          |
+---------+---------+---------------+
| praveen |    Like | Praveen Kumar |
|    jeff | Comment | Jeff Atwood   |
| praveen |  Answer | Praveen Kumar |
| praveen |   Share | Praveen Kumar |
|    jeff | Comment | Jeff Atwood   |
|   bluff |   Share | (null)        |
|    jeff |    Like | Jeff Atwood   |
+---------+---------+---------------+
```

**Expected Output**

```
+---------+---------+---------------+
| USER    | ACTION  | NAME          |
+---------+---------+---------------+
| praveen |    Like | Praveen Kumar |
|    jeff | Comment | Jeff Atwood   |
| praveen |  Answer | Praveen Kumar |
| praveen |   Share | Praveen Kumar |
|    jeff | Comment | Jeff Atwood   |
|   bluff |   Share | bluff         |
|    jeff |    Like | Jeff Atwood   |
+---------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: You could just wrap you subquery in a test (e.g. `IFNULL()`, `COALESCE()`, `IF()` or `CASE ... END`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `IFNULL`

```
SELECT *, IFNULL((
  SELECT `fullname` FROM `users` WHERE `user` = `username`
),`user`) AS `name` FROM `actions`
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2bdd/9)

**EDIT:**

Also `COALESCE` does the same

```
SELECT *, COALESCE((
  SELECT `fullname` FROM `users` WHERE `user` = `username`
),`user`) AS `name` FROM `actions`
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks. I guess using `IFNULL`, but didn't know how to use it. :)

Comment: MySQL coalesce() function returns the first non-NULL value of a list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values. - http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php

Answer (score 3):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` with `CASE` statement like this:

```
SELECT User, Action 
       ,CASE WHEN Fullname IS NULL 
             THEN User 
             ELSE Fullname 
              END as Name
FROM actions a
LEFT JOIN users u
ON a.User = u.username;
```

OUTPUT

```
|    USER |  ACTION |          NAME |
-------------------------------------
| praveen |    Like | Praveen Kumar |
|    jeff | Comment |   Jeff Atwood |
| praveen |  Answer | Praveen Kumar |
| praveen |   Share | Praveen Kumar |
|    jeff | Comment |   Jeff Atwood |
|   bluff |   Share |         bluff |
|    jeff |    Like |   Jeff Atwood |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2bdd/14)

Comment: @PraveenKumar - This is not complex. This is basic `Left Join` which is ideal for such situation.

Comment: I am accepting the other answer, which is what I am using. I have `+1`d :)

Comment: I don't use left join in many of my cases, because it would give me double ups if the record was in the right table twice.. thats why a subquery is better and do a select top 1, that way I get one value. or the value of IFNULL

Comment: @hamish: That depends on your data structure and expected output. Also performance wise [joins are better than sub-queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rewriting-subqueries.html).

Comment: in this case (and yes its a very very common case) you are expecting just one value for one cell. hence if you get two rows then you are screwed. I see soo many complaints from users about duplicate rows in productions systems it drives me insane that developers think that using a join in this situation is ok :) just saying. and I see 3 developers agree with you.  so i guess we can agree to disagree on the what is good for the users :)  which is normally dictated by the developer, who knows better, right :)

Comment: I have used this solution in the past, when used in combination with Group By User, Action. and Max(name).   It works quite well as a method for succeeding in pivoting data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the accepted answer, I went with this in my production code, and the performance is amazing. Notice the mysql usage of LIMIT 1 (similar to sql server's  SELECT TOP 1).  And note the combined usage of COALESCE and CONCAT, i.e. the extra comma is not appended if the suburb is null, because ', ' + null = null, which then using coalesce then becomes empty string.

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE((SELECT Customer.Name From Customer WHERE Quote.CustomerId = Customer.Id LIMIT 1), '') As CustomerName, 
    Description, 
    (CONCAT(COALESCE(DeliveryStreet, ''), COALESCE(CONCAT(', ', DeliverySuburb), ''), COALESCE(CONCAT(', ', DeliveryCity), ''), COALESCE(CONCAT(', ', DeliveryPostcode), ''))) as DeliveryAddress, 
    COALESCE(DATE_FORMAT(CreatedDate, '%d %b %y'), '') as QuoteCreatedDate, 
    COALESCE((SELECT User.Name FROM QuoteStatusHistory INNER JOIN Status ON Status.Id = QuoteStatusHistory.StatusId INNER JOIN User ON QuoteStatusHistory.UserId = User.Id WHERE QuoteStatusHistory.QuoteId = Quote.Id AND QuoteStatusHistory.StatusId = 1 ORDER BY QuoteStatusHistory.CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1), '') as CreatedBy, 
    COALESCE((SELECT DATE_FORMAT(QuoteStatusHistory.CreatedDate, '%d %b %y') FROM QuoteStatusHistory WHERE QuoteStatusHistory.QuoteId = Quote.Id AND QuoteStatusHistory.StatusId = 2 ORDER BY QuoteStatusHistory.CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1), '') as OrderDate, 
    COALESCE((SELECT User.Name FROM QuoteStatusHistory INNER JOIN Status ON Status.Id = QuoteStatusHistory.StatusId INNER JOIN User ON QuoteStatusHistory.UserId = User.Id WHERE QuoteStatusHistory.QuoteId = Quote.Id AND QuoteStatusHistory.StatusId = 2 ORDER BY QuoteStatusHistory.CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1), '') as OrderedBy, 
    COALESCE((SELECT DATE_FORMAT(QuoteStatusHistory.CreatedDate, '%d %b %y') FROM QuoteStatusHistory WHERE QuoteStatusHistory.QuoteId = Quote.Id AND QuoteStatusHistory.StatusId IN (3, 4) ORDER BY QuoteStatusHistory.CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1), '') as DispatchDate, 
    QuotePrice,
    COALESCE((SELECT Status.Name FROM QuoteStatusHistory INNER JOIN Status ON Status.Id = QuoteStatusHistory.StatusId WHERE QuoteStatusHistory.QuoteId = Quote.Id ORDER BY QuoteStatusHistory.CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1), '') as QuoteStatus 
FROM Quote
```